# In Typescript how can I set types for querySelectorAll with the spread syntax

Tags: typescript, selectors-api, spread-syntax

I have this code.

```
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.someClass')]
```

Combination of:

- querySelectorAll
- the spread operator

I can't figure out how to add Typescript types to this line.

I get errors from the console:

```
TS2548: Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not an array type or does not have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you target `es5` it doesn't work since TypeScript doesn't support filling in / polyfiling for `Symbol.iterator`

If you target `es6` it will work.

Alternatively you can use `Array.from` using the `lib` option:

```
const elements = [...Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.someClass'))]
```

Or more simply:

```
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.someClass'))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I will try the `Array.from()` suggestion.

Would I be right in thinking that Babel's conversion is imperfect and that Typescript sticks to true conversions on principle? Thus, no way to opt in to convert the spread operator as Babel does.

I'm quite a beginner at Typescript, is there a recommended way to "Type Up" the `Array.from()` version?